# Can params be used to pass variables by ref via a function using yield

Tags: c#, yield, parameters

If I have a method that has a `params` parameter, can it be passed by reference and updated every time a yield is called.

Something like this:

```
public static void GetRowsIter(ref params valuesToUpdate)
{

    foreach(row in rows)
    {
       foreach(param in valuesToUpdate
       {
          GetValueForParam(param)
       }
       yield;
    }
}
```

Is that legal?  (I am away from my compiler or I would just try it out.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `params` just creates an array that contains the parameters being passed. This array, like all others, is just a collection of variables, and it's not possible to declare a `ref` variable or array type. Because of this only actual explicit parameters can be passed as `ref` or `out`.

That being said, if the type is a reference type then it will exhibit reference type semantics as usual, meaning that any changes made *to the object* will be reflected in all code that has access to that reference. Only *assignments to the actual variable* would not be reflected.

However, I'm not certain exactly what your code is intended to do. The `yield` statement either has to be followed by the `return` statement and a value or by the `break` statement, which ends the iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was trying to code a way to return a variable amount of values via the yield statement.  Looks like that is not going to be possible (at least not this way).

Comment: @Vaccano: You can certainly return a variable number of values, but they can't be `ref`.