# How to write method which will accept variable count of parameters by ref

Tags: c#

So, I have the following code

```
int[] GetIndexes(string columns)
{
  ...
}

var indexes = GetIndexes("Code|Name|Description");
var codeIndex = indexes[0];
var nameIndex = indexes[1];
var descIndex = indexes[2];
```

It is preferred to use it in the next way:

```
GetIndexes("Code|Name|Description", ref codeIndex, ref nameIndex, ref descIndex);
```

Have you any suggestion about it?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776020/interesting-params-of-ref-feature-any-workarounds and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176884/can-params-be-used-to-pass-variables-by-ref-via-a-function-using-yield?

Comment: Keep using the version with the return type. IMO it is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own class to acquire the indexes. See how:

```
class IndexReceiver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator IndexReceiver(string name)
    {
        return new IndexReceiver() { Name = name };
    }
}
```

Then, you define your method like this:

```
void GetIndexes(params IndexReceiver[] receivers)
{
    // Here you read the each IndexReceiver's Name property and write the index.
}
```

Use the new method like this:

```
IndexReceiver code = "Code", index = "Index", desc = "desc"
GetIndexes(code, index, desc);
```

Comment: Instead of `explicit`, this should be `implicit`.